# How to document usage of a method when called in an abstract form?

Tags: php, oop, phpstorm, phpdoc

In a legacy project, I was confused when I tried finding the usage of a method in phpstorm and without success.

```
/**
 * @param SomeEntity[] $someEntity
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function warmupSomeEntity(array $brandUniverses)
{
     // I want to find this method's usage

}
```

Debugging a bit further, I found that the method is called on the fly in a rather abstract way via dynamic class method invocation:

```
/**
 * @param string $warmer
 * @param array $objects
 *
 * @throws RuntimeException
 */
public function warmupType($warmer, array $objects)
{
    $method = "warmup$warmer";
    if (method_exists($this, $
        $this->{$method}($objects);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("There is no warmer '$warmer'");
    }
}
```

Is there a phpdoc syntax where I can document that the `warmUpType` method will call `warmupSomeEntity`, or `warmupSomeOtherEntity` so that I can find its usage again if I want to jump to the calling code block again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [@uses keyword](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.uses.pkg.html) was what I was looking for as it:

> Display a link to the documentation for an element, and create a backlink in the other element's documentation to this

It is supported by PhpStorm and the caller is found again.

```
/**
 * @param string $warmer
 * @param array $objects
 * @uses warmupSomeEntity
 * @uses warmupSomeOtherEntity
 * @throws RuntimeException
 */
public function warmupType($warmer, array $objects)
{
 ...
}
```